# Can't reconcile workspace on Gated Check-in

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019, tfvc, gated-checkin

My workspace is not reconciling after a gated check-in.  I don't see an error.  My files are checked in, but still showing under pending changes.

- Doing a compare with latest shows no differences.
- If I bypass the gated check-in, it reconciles as expected.
- Clicking 'Reconcile
  Workspace' on the build menu shows a dialog that says 'No changes to
  reconcile'.
- Restarting Visual Studio does not reconcile.

Our team just received new computers and everyone is having this problem.  This did require us to install the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.4).  I'm not sure if it's a problem with the latest Visual studio, or the new computer.

Any advice on how to resolve this?